# Oracle not returning expected results when using FETCH NEXT X ROWS ONLY in combination with ORDER BY

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, oracle12c, oracle19c

When working with Oracle 12c and implementing pagination I came across a problem when using `ORDER BY` in combination with `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT <X> ROWS ONLY`.

## Example

My testing table `test`:

```
+----+---------------------+
| ID |        NAME         |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | Customer Support    |
|  2 | Property Management |
|  3 | Security            |
|  4 | Security            |
|  5 | Security            |
|  6 | Security            |
|  7 | Tax Compliance      |
+----+---------------------+
```

I am running following SQL:

```
SELECT  id
FROM            test
ORDER BY        name ASC   
OFFSET <offset> ROWS   
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

With these results:

```
+--------+--------+-----------------+
| Offset | Result | Expected result |
+--------+--------+-----------------+
|      0 |      1 |               1 |
|      1 |      2 |               2 |
|      2 |      3 |               3 |
|      3 |      4 |               4 |
|      4 |      4 |               5 |
|      5 |      4 |               6 |
|      6 |      7 |               7 |
+--------+--------+-----------------+
```

## Question

The question is why is the DB not returning the expected result?

When no `ORDER BY` is used it works flawlessly. Is this kind of use prohibited? Am I using it wrongly? If so could you please point me to the documentation where it says that this kind of usage is not possible. The version I am using is 12c but the same behaviour applies to 19c.

## More example queries

### Query with `OFFSET` only:

```
SELECT  id
FROM            test
ORDER BY        name ASC   
OFFSET 4 ROWS;
```

Result:

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
+----+
```

### Query with `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY`:

```
SELECT  id
FROM            test
ORDER BY        name ASC   
OFFSET 4 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Result:

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  4 |
+----+
```

Thank you

Adam

Comment: Hi @klajmajk you say: "I am running following SQL:" can you show me the exact sql you are running ? Thanks!

Comment: I might not have been clear in my original question but for the resulting table I run `SELECT  id
FROM            test
ORDER BY        name ASC 
OFFSET X ROWS   
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;` where X are numbers from 0 to 6 (so it was 7 queries). The thing that is mind-boggling for me is that if omit the `FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY` then I get the expected result. For example for `OFFSET 4` resulting in ids 5, 6, 7 but if I limit it with `FETCH NEXT` I get 4...

Comment: So you are telling me that your example data is not correct ? You have more than 1 rows of data with id = 4 and name = Security  ?

Comment: Also, please add one query to the question that gives you this: "For example for OFFSET 4 resulting in ids 5, 6, 7" and one query that gives you this "but if I limit it with FETCH NEXT I get 4..." And explain in one sentence this query's. I believe it would help.

Comment: No each row has unique id 1 - 7

Comment: @VBoka I added more examples to the question. Hope it is clear now. Thank you

Comment: ok, and  what is the reason that explanation from GMB is not clear to you ? I suggest you add 2 more rows like this: `insert into test values(8, 'Security')` and `insert into test values(9, 'Security')` and you will see it will be even more messed up. So My suggestion is to go to some fiddle and play with data and offset. I believe it will make some things clear to you... Before that accept @GMB answer...Just a suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ORDER BY` clause produces ties since multiple records have the same `name`. In this case, it is undefined which record will be picked.

From your expected results, I understand that you want a second ordering criteria by `id`:

```
SELECT id
FROM test
ORDER BY name, id
OFFSET <offset> ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more why is the tie a problem? When there is no ORDER BY clause it works. And it works if I do this: 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT  id
FROM            departments
ORDER BY        name ASC)   
OFFSET 3 ROWS   
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;

Comment: @klajmajk: you need a criteria to kreak the ties. Otherwise, it is undefined which row will be considered first. You might see the result that you expect when you run this or that query, but there is no guarantee that you will get the same results in subsequent executions (unless, again, an unambiguous sorting rule is provided).

Comment: @GMB just a question, from OP's table, the ID's are from 1 to 7(and this is data). Offset is a row limiting clause. So offset can maybe return 1235647 or 7654321 or 1234567 but it can not return 1234447 right? And OP say's that he gets the results 1234447 from the above table. Am I understanding this in a wrong way. Thanks for you time. Cheers!

Comment: It's not that simple, row limiting does a **top-n query**, similar to the FIRST_ROWS(n) hint. The optimizer often implements this by using an index to find the specific rows requested, skipping the rest of the rows. If you have multiple rows tied in the index, your result is undefined.

Comment: Hi @kfinity, thanks for your answer, let me just explain my question. As you can see in OP's questio, he said : "My testing table test:" and " am running following SQL:" and "With these results:". And that statement is not possible. That is what I wanted to say...

Comment: @VBoka: kfinity is correct. Without an *unambiguous* `order by` clause, the ordering of the rows in the resultset is *undefined*. You are assuming that subsequent executions will produce the same order, but this is in no way guaranteed. Different executions could return different orders, like `1234567`, 1265437 `, `1236457`, `1246537`, and so on. Hence the results that OP is getting.

Comment: No no, you do not understand. My comments are from the text where op wrote his result is 1234447. And you can see that even now. And that is not possible to get with offset for data 1234567. But I understand OP, later on, this is the mix of different query's and results...

Comment: @VBoka: the results OP is showing correspond to *consecutive executions* of the same query, with different values of `offset`.

Comment: Yes, And that is the part I did not understood at first, I was thinking that it is from one offset query and there comes my confusion from. As you can see, later on, when I understood that part of the question I have asked the OP what is then the problem, all is clear and suggested him to accept this answer as you can see in the comments...